# How to organize and load CSS within Django project/app?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django. I read the Documentation and I am literally confused with media root files and static root files and where I should be placing my css files along with my javascript files.

Can you guys point me in the correct direction?
Project setup:

```
Project
     -myapp
         -model,view,and test
     -template
         - base.html
         - index.html
         - view1
         - view2
         - media
             - css
                 - style.css
                 - ie.css
             - js
             - img

     -setting.py
     -url.py
```

What should my static_url, static_root, media_url , media_root, STATICFILES_DIRS and STATICFILES_FINDERS look like?

How I currently load my css file is through the base.html with the following:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static user_stylesheet %}"type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

So what is the best and most efficient/correct way of managing my static files?
Thank you everybody for your help. I appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Static files are a simple process:

- Django will search for a directory named `static/` inside any app that is in `INSTALLED_APPS` for static files. If you have files that are not tied to any app, you can put them in a separate directory. This directory should be added to `STATICFILES_DIRS` (a tuple) so django is aware of it. In your case you should have `STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/home/user/Project/template/media',)`
- Add `django.contrib.staticfiles` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Now, if you are testing this with `runserver`, open your `urls.py` and add `from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns` to the top, and after all your URLs are defined, at the end of the file, add `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()`

You already have the correct method of accessing static files in your question. The other way is to use `{{ STATIC_URL }}`, and make sure you are sending your responses with `RequestContext`. If you are using class based views, you don't have to change anything. For your other normal view methods, just use the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render).

---

`STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` come in handy when you are deploying.

- `STATIC_URL` is the URL prefix that your web server has been configured with to point to the location in the system that has your static files. This is a *url component* and *must end in a slash*. For example `/static/`
- `STATIC_ROOT` this is a path to a directory on your system. When you are ready to deploy, run the `collectstatic` command and django will find all your static files and dump them in the directory pointed to by `STATIC_ROOT`. Then you can take this directory, put it in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder that your web server is configured with. Then, point the `/static/` URL to this folder. Example is `STATIC_ROOT = /home/user/project/www/`

If Apache is configured with a `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of `/var/www/`, and your `STATIC_URL` setting is `/static/`; after you run `collectstatic`, move the contents of the folder `/home/user/project/www/` to `/var/www/static/`.

---

- `STATICFILES_FINDERS`. This setting lists methods that django can use to search for your static files when you run `collectstatic`, and you normally don't modify this at all.

---

- `MEDIA_ROOT`, `MEDIA_URL`. These settings control the file system location, and the URL prefix of any files that are **uploaded using django**; these ***cannot be the same as `STATICFILES_DIRS`***.  You need to handle this manually as `collectstatic` will not touch these locations.  If you are testing file uploads in development, you can use [`django.views.static.serve()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#django.views.static.serve) to serve files from `MEDIA*`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to keep all your js and css files in a folder named, 'static' some where outside your application folder (that's how django recommends it) 
For example, if you keep it under /var/www/static/ 
So, in this case this is how your attributes would look like:
STATIC_DIR = "/var/www/static/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/" (Can be anything)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',)

In the template you can refer the static folder using template tag {{STATIC_URL}} and append the rest of the path to the file from the static folder. Note, to use the {{STATIC_URL}} template tag you would need to pass the context_instance from the view code.

Answer (score 1):

Media serving is Django is a "thing".

You can see the link to the docs here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

But the magic bit is as follows ** IF THIS IS NOT IN PRODUCTION ** you probably need to add the following to the bottom of your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

For the production server you serve media old school style by your webserver (apache or whatever), using the same domain but effectively completely independently of your Django/Python site.