# How to setup static files in Django

Tags: django, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to organize and load CSS within Django project/app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041861/how-to-organize-and-load-css-within-django-project-app)

I have follow several websites about how to setup static files in Django. Here are my steps.

Configure the setting.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/kin/mysite/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Run the collectstatic command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

After that, I saw my image file is copied to the STATIC_ROOT.

Then in my template, I try to use my image file by:

```
<img border="0" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images.jpg" width="304" height="228">
```

But there is no image when I load it on the browser. I checked the page source and STATIC_URL seems empty.

Can anyone shed some light here?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add `django.contrib.staticfiles` to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is a default app on the settings.py

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13549755/790387

Answer (score 5):

Dont hard code the path in your setting. I usually put my static files in my main project, so my setting file look like this

```
import os
MAIN_PROJECT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

then

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''
# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(MAIN_PROJECT, 'static/'),
)
```

After that, you can use `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in your view

Answer (score 4):

Actually I got it right by just using the following code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img border="0" src="{% static 'image.jpg' %}" width="304" height="228">
```

This will render the STATIC_URL path to me.

Thanks all for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

If you're running your app with `python manage.py runserver` then you may need to add the following to the end of your url conf (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)).

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

The process for serving static files with django's dev server is different to the process for doing it with a production web server.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this

import settings in `urls.py` 
and paste the below code in your urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.static',
    (r'^static_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 
        'serve', {
        'document_root': 'path/to/your/static/folder',
        'show_indexes': True }),)
```

now go to your settings.py  and change the setting like

```
MEDIA_URL = '/static_media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

now access your static file like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}css/header.css" />
```